# Invoke-Command does not exit after execution of batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file which starts the application and closes after execution, when same batch is called through PowerShell, PowerShell executes the batch file contents but does not execute the next line in the script.

Batch file content mentioned below:

```
start "some application"
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3 > nul
EXIT \B
```

When called with PowerShell it prints the `EXIT/B` in PowerShell window but does not executes next line.

PowerShell script content:

```
$remote_lpc0 =  "10.53.216.28"
$password0 = ConvertTo-SecureString "yt_xk39b"-AsPlainText -Force 
$cred0 = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential("reglpc", $password0)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remote_lpc0 -Credential $cred0 -ScriptBlock {
    C:\GIT\registers_e2e\HLRPerformanceScripts\common\start.bat
}
echo "hello"
```

How do I exit the batch file context and execute the next line of code?

Comment: Why there's an idle ping in the batch anyway? If you need to wait for awhile, there's `start-sleep` in Powershell. In addition, there's both `exit /b`, and `exit \b`, so please make sure there are no typos.

Comment: i have kept the idle ping just to make sure application is started before exiting the batch file. but in powershell the batch file is called but not exiting and executing next line of the powershell script , like the simple echo statement which i am trying to print

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: Hello. Try this, maybe it help: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remote_lpc0 -Credential $cred0 -ScriptBlock {
   Start-Process -FilePath C:\GIT\registers_e2e\HLRPerformanceScripts\common\start.bat }`

Comment: [`start "" "some application"`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) because `start "some application"` starts a new `cmd` instance with `some application` **title**.